# DOMPurify.sanitize() throws an error in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I displaying HTML content from object in NextJS. I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to display that HTML data. But to avoid XSS attacks I am trying to santize HTML with **DOMPurify**. `__html: [rawhtml]` works but `DOMPurify.sanitize([rawhtml])` throws an error like this `TypeError: dompurify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.sanitize is not a function`. How to resolve this issue?

```js
let HtmlData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    rawhtml: `
      <div>
        <h1>Tada</h1>
      </div>
    `,
  },
];

const ShowData = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {HtmlData.map(({ rawhtml, id }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <div
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize([rawhtml]) }}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I hope this will help you... https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/issues/29#issuecomment-466626162